# SPF Passes In Gmail Original Mail but says failed in Dmarc report

Tags: email-validation, spf, dmarc

I'm using a 3rd party service to send emails through my gmail account(with a custom domain).  There is a weird thing happening with my SPF authentication.

When I look at the "original email" in a recipient's inbox, it says the SPF passed.

However, on the daily DMARC report it says the SPF failed. (See below)

Any idea why this is and how to fix it? Thank you!

Original Email details:

Subject:    PR Wed Test 04

SPF:    PASS with IP 209.85.220.41 Learn more

DKIM:   'PASS' with domain rmtdigitalsolutions.com Learn more

DMARC:  'PASS' Learn more

Dmarc report:

<source_ip>209.85.220.41</source_ip>

```
  <count>1</count>

  <policy_evaluated>

    <disposition>none</disposition>

    <dkim>pass</dkim>

    <spf>fail</spf>
```

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70032702/12917821

Comment: Yes, I think Kasper’s answer is likely what you’re looking for. Alignment is key wrt to DMARC. SPF and DKIM don’t care about alignment. Dmarc, the policy layer, worries about alignment.