# Gmail DMARC/DKIM/SPF results vs. DMARC reports

Tags: email, gmail, spf, dkim, dmarc

I recently noticed a discrepancy between Gmail's DMARC/DKIM/SPF results for messages sent via my mailserver as represented in the mail headers –

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.com header.s=s42 header.b=TWJ2lYx3;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@domain.com designates 000.000.000.000 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@domain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.com
Return-Path: <user@domain.com>
Received: from mail.domain.com (mail.domain.com. [000.000.000.000])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v16-20020a5d6110000000b00314105346a6si1394751wrt.420.2023.07.06.12.09.26
        for <mygmailaccount@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Thu, 06 Jul 2023 12:09:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@domain.com designates 000.000.000.000 as permitted sender) client-ip=000.000.000.000;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.com header.s=s42 header.b=TWJ2lYx3;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@domain.com designates 000.000.000.000 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@domain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=domain.com
```

– and Google's DMARC report, which contains a `fail` result for the same messages:

```
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>1502902575606731331</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1688515200</begin>
      <end>1688601599</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>domain.com</domain>
    <adkim>s</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>quarantine</p>
    <sp>quarantine</sp>
    <pct>75</pct>
    <np>quarantine</np>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>000.000.000.000</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>quarantine</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mail.domain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail.domain.com</domain>
        <result>none</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

A couple of months ago, Google's reports listed `pass` results (and Microsoft's reports still do).

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062584/spf-passes-in-gmail-original-mail-but-says-failed-in-dmarc-report), but the response pointing to misaligned domains does not apply here, as the domains are properly aligned for my relaxed DMARC policy (s. snippets above with `domain.com` and `mail.doman.com` as placeholders for my actual domains). What's more, the DMARC result is different in the message header and the report, too.

Comment: The report and headers don't belong together. Too many differences.

Comment: I modified some data for privacy purposes, but the pattern is consistent: Headers show PASS results, DMARC reports contain FAIL results.

Comment: Check this: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/210298

Comment: My problem is not that SPF, DKIM or DMARC tests fail – they succeed (according to the Gmail raw view)! But Google's own DMARC reports disagree and list failures for all tests.